# PHP SQLite3 query not displaying all rows

Tags: sqlite

I have a PHP script show below that queries for all rows. The result set only shows one row even though there are more.

mbrlist.php

```
`<?php  
  $html = "";  
  
  class MyDB extends SQLite3   
  {  
    function __construct()   
    {  
      $this->open('privdata/helpseekers.db');  
    }  
  }  

  $db = new MyDB();  

  if ( !$db )   
  {  
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
  }   
  else   
  {  
    $rows = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM accounts");  
    $row = $rows->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);  
    $numRows = $row['count'];  
    echo "Opened database successfully - " . $numRows . " Accounts Found\n";  
  }

  $ret = $db->query("SELECT id,userid,fname,lname,password,email,userrole FROM accounts ORDER BY id ASC");  

  while ( $rec = $ret->fetchArray() )  
  {  
      $html  = "  <td>{$rec[0]}</td>  <td>{$rec[1]}</td>  <td>{$rec[2]}</td>  <td>{$rec[3]}</td>    <td>{$rec[4]}</td>  <td>{$rec[5]}</td>  <td>{$rec[6]}</td> </tr>\n";  
      if ( !$rec = $ret->fetchArray() ) break;  
  }  
  $db->close();  
  echo $html;  
?>`
```

So why does it not return more than one row?

Comment: You fetch array twice in the loop. The one in the loop should not exist.

Comment: Yes on several other sitess the one will not display all rows. The claim is that the one in the loop will.

Comment: BTW yes I have tried it both ways. Neither works. Hence the reason I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop you do :

```
// Before loop variable html contains ""
// on next line you set into $rec the next row data
// in case there is no more row you exit or not not enter the loop
while ( $rec = $ret->fetchArray() )  
{  
  // anything that was inside $html before this assignment is replaced
  // by <td>...</td> of current row
  $html  = "  <td>{$rec[0]}</td>  <td>{$rec[1]}</td>  <td>{$rec[2]}</td>  <td>{$rec[3]}</td>    <td>{$rec[4]}</td>  <td>{$rec[5]}</td>  <td>{$rec[6]}</td> </tr>\n";  
  // here you get the next row in $rec and test if it is not null
  // if it is null you exit the loop
  if ( !$rec = $ret->fetchArray() ) break;

  // at the end of the loop, the code in while ($rec = ...) is 
  // executed to get row of next data  
}  
$db->close();

// here you send the contents of $html to client browser  
echo $html;
```

Comment: That may be true for a single row. But this is a loop. Each row would do this with new data. What would be output is the data for each row formatted as a <table><tr><td>. It is necessary to make $html = and not .= because it is not a continuation of the previous record but a new record entirely.

Comment: The $html code is send only when you do echo $html; so only once after the end of the loop with its contents at this moment.

Comment: So the $rec = $ret->fetchArray() means nothing? I think that is the source of the data in the $html line. Otherwise there would be nothing in $rec. The whlle ($rec = $ret->fetchArray()) get the data array for $rec. Then the html fills in the data as an HTML statement. At least that is my current understanding.

Comment: added some more comments in the answer . Hope this will help you understand

Comment: Answering your comment got me to thinking about this loop. Actually the echo $html should be in the loop to output each HTML statement one at a time instead waiting until the exit of the loop.